# How to execute Bit logic with Math expressions in C# that return as a boolean result?

Tags: c#, bitmap

I am converting legacy VB.NET code to C# and have stumbled across a bit logic expression that for the life of me cannot translate to C#.

The VB.NET snippet below basically evaluates each math expression and based on the boolean result, it sets the array index to that boolean value.

```
    Public Function createBigEndianBitArray(ByVal bt() As Byte) As BitArray
    Dim boolAra() As Boolean
    Dim ba As BitArray
    Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
    Dim cur_index As Integer
    ' get the length of the byte array and multiply by 8 for the
    ' length of the boolean array
    ReDim boolAra((bt.Length * 8) - 1)

    cur_index = 0 ' boolean array index

    ' iterate through the byte array
    For x = 0 To bt.Length - 1
        ' iterate through each byte
        For y = 7 To 0 Step -1
            boolAra(cur_index) = bt(x) And 2 ^ y
            cur_index += 1
        Next
    Next

    ba = New BitArray(boolAra)
    Return ba
End Function
```

In C#, online translator were completely hosed up and the only way I am able to even get it to compile is by wrapping both math expressions in a Convert.Boolean(). However, when i compare the output of both, they are vastly different results meaning the bit logic isn't working the same.

```
    public BitArray createBigEndianBitArray(byte[] bt)
    {
        bool[] boolAra;
        BitArray ba;
        int x;
        int y;
        int cur_index;
        // get the length of the byte array and multiply by 8 for the
        // length of the boolean array
        boolAra = new bool[(bt.Length * 8)];

        cur_index = 0; // boolean array index

        // iterate through the byte array
        for (x = 0; x <= bt.Length - 1; x++)
        {
            // iterate through each byte
            for (y = 7; y >= 0; y += -1)
            {
                boolAra[cur_index] = Convert.ToBoolean(bt[x]) & Convert.ToBoolean(Math.Pow(2, y));
                cur_index += 1;
            }
        }

        ba = new BitArray(boolAra);
        return ba;
    }
```

Comment: I think you probably want one `Convert.ToBoolean` to wrap around the whole thing, rather than two `Convert.ToBoolean` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign an integer to a boolean in VB, it's actually testing if the integer is equal to zero, so the C# equivalent is:

```
for (y = 7; y >= 0; y--)
{
    boolAra[cur_index] = (bt[x] & (byte)Math.Pow(2, y)) != 0;
    cur_index += 1;
}
```

Comment: This was a good answer and I also came up with this which provides the same result as the VB.NET evaluation so there is a few ways to solve it. I'v never seen this type of expression before so it hung me up for a good while lol. Here is what code i got working: boolAra[cur_index] = Convert.ToBoolean(((sbyte)bt[x]) & ((sbyte)Math.Pow(2, y)));

Comment: I did update my code to this answer tho as it's cleaner to read :)